# What does the notation $T\,|_A$ stand for linear matrix operator $T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm reading about linear algebra and I came across with the following notation which is not explained in my reference. The notation is:

> $$T|_A,$$

where $T$ is a linear operator (square matrix) on complex vector space $V$ and $A$ is a subset of $V$. In my reference I found this notation in the following statement:

> $$\text{each }\;(T-\lambda_jI)\,|_{U_j}\; \text{is nilpotent}$$

where $\lambda_j$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ and $U_j$ is a set of generalized eigenvectors of $T$ corresponding to $\lambda_j$.

**Question:** What does this notation mean? If it means the restriction of $T$ to the vectors in $A$ then what is the actual difference between $T$ and $T\,|_A$? Are they different linear transformations or are they equal?

**Subquestion:** if $T\,|_A$ is nilpotent, then does this also imply that $T$ is also nilpotent?

UPDATE:

Comment: It just means $T$ restricted to values in $A$. $T$'s domain is $V$.

Comment: As for your subquestion, I would think not since you are restricting to only a subset and not the whole space. But the converse is true.

Comment: So $T\,|_A$ and $T$ are equal?

Comment: No, they are the same map with different domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$T \colon V \to V, x \mapsto T(x)$$ be a linear operator and $A \subseteq V$. Then by definition
$$T|_A \colon A \to V, x \mapsto T(x).$$

You see that $T$ and $T|_A$ differ by the domain they are defined on. Also note that one can interpret functions as subsets of the cartesian product of their domain and the target space, i.e. as relations, i.e. as sets. In this case $T \subseteq V \times W$ but $T|_A \subseteq A \times W$.

If $A$ is not a linear subspace $T|_A$ might not be linear anymore. When working with operators one often only restricts the operator to so called "invariant" subspaces, i.e. subspaces $A \subseteq V$ such that $T(A) \subseteq A$. This guarantees the well-definedness of powers of the restriction.

Consider the linear mapping $$F_M \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2, x \mapsto M \cdot x$$ with $$M := \left(\begin{matrix}
  0 & 0  \\
  0 & 1 
 \end{matrix}\right).$$

Consider now the linear subspace $A := \operatorname{span}\{e_1\}$. Clearly $F_M|_A$ is nilpotent while $F_M$ isn't.

But of course the restriction of an already nilpotent linear map to an invariant subspace is again nilpotent!

Comment: I'm confused totally xD I thought that a matrix being nilpotent or not is completely independent from its domain. But it seems this is not the case? In this case I do not understand what it means for matrix to be nilpotent. This is how I think about it: lets say $T^2=TT=0$ so $T$ is a nilpotent matrix. In this case for all vector spaces we have $T^2 x = (TT)x = 0 x = 0$.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I edited my post.

Comment: No problem at all. Much appreciate your help! =)

Comment: Note that you have to differ between matrices and operators. Each Matrix induces an operator, as above: Matrix $M$ induces the operator $F_M$. But the operator $F_M$ is not nilpotent. If we restrict the operator $F_M$ to the subspace $A$ as above $F_M|_A$ becomes nilpotent.

Comment: BUT: An operator is nilpotent if and only if its representation matrix is nilpotent. Of course the representation matrix of $F_M$ with respect to the standard basis $(e_1, e_2)$ is $M$. But what is the representation matrix of the restriction $F_M|A$ with respect to the basis $e_1$ (Basis of $A$)?

Comment: I think I now finally got it. I think there was a confusion in communication because I did not express my question clearly enough :) No matter I got it now :) Thank you once again! Big respect!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Just adding one (important) aspect of your cited example. When saying that 
$T_{|A}$ is nilpotent (with $A$ being a subspace) implicitly assumes
that $T_{|A} \circ T_{|A}$ is defined and for this you need $T(A)\subset A$. I think this was not mentioned in other posts...

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed just the restriction of the domain. So $T|_A$ and $T$ are in fact different, since two function on different domains cannot be equal, by definition.

No, $T_A$ being nilpotent does not imply that $T$ is nilpotent. Consider e.g. 
$$f:b_1\mapsto b_1, b_2\mapsto 0$$
defined on the vector space $\langle b_1,b_2\rangle_\mathbb{R}$. Then $f|_{\langle b_2\rangle}$ is nilpotent, but $f$ is not.

Comment: You cannot say $f|_{\langle b_2\rangle}$ is nilpotent because it is not an operator at all - it does not send ${\langle b_2\rangle}$ to ${\langle b_2\rangle}$.

Comment: But the transformations are still the same aren't they? I mean if you have e.g. the function $f(x)=x^2$ restricted to domain where $x>0$ or whole domain $\mathbb{R}$, then aren't the transformations still the same? i.e. the mapping function.

Comment: @heptagon Sorry, typo. Fixed

Comment: @jjepsuomi No, a function is a triple $(X,Y,R)$, where $X,Y$ are sets, and $R$ is a relation (a special type of relation, namely a function). Hence restricting changes the function, since it changes the triple. This should also be clear from the fact that the restriction can be nilpotent, while the main function is not. This clearly indicates that these cannot be the same function. Similarly, the restriction can be injective, while the main function is not. Also, the main function can be surjective, while the restriction is not.

Answer (score 2):

For your subquestion - Consider $T:R\ ^ 2 \to R \ ^ 2$ defined by 
$T(x,y) = (x,0) $

Chose $W = sp(0,1)$ so $T(W) = 0 $ so $T|_W $ is nilpotent.

And what about T ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused now :) I thought that if we state that square matrix is nilpotent for some $k>0$, then to me this means that $T^k = 0$ regardless of what domain we are working in. This is where my confusion is: lets say $x_1$ and $x_2$ are from different domains. Then $T^k x_1 = \mathbf{0}x_1 = 0$ and $T^k x_2 = \mathbf{0}x_2 = 0$.

Comment: To be nilpotent (matrix or linear transformation )  means that there exists $k \in N $ s.t $T \ ^ k = 0 $ (and this, btw, means that for each $m \ge k  T \ ^ m = 0$) (tell me if you don't understand why) , in my example $T|_W $ is nilpotent with $k=1 $ but T isn't because you can't find $k $ s.t $T \ ^ k =0 $ for all $v \in R \ ^ 2 $. is that clearer now ? @jjepsuomi

Comment: also $T \ ^ k = 0 $ is a short way of writing $T(v) \ ^ k = 0 $ for each $v \in Dom(T) $

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! =)

Answer (score 1):

Concerning Question, you are right. The difference is that the domains of these functions are different. So this does not make sense to tell if they are equal or not. They cannot be equal because they are functions with different domains.

Concerning Subquestion, no. Imagine the operator defined as $e_1\to e_1$ and $e_2\to0$ on the basis vectors. It is not nilpotent, but its restriction on the subspace spanned by $e_2$ is zero.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help =)